# Is it possible to access a locally stored static variable at different run times

Tags: java, variables, storage

I need some help because I am new to Java Programming.

I have a program to store an element assume "TotalOrders". Here I am updating this variable value after the each call to addition and removal of orders. When I run the program in different times it has to check the previously stored value in "TotalOrders".
Ex. Initially TotalOrders = 0, After addition of 4 Orders, TotalOrders = 4,
after removal of 2 Orders, TotalOrders = 2.

When I run a program at some time it has to check whether TotalOrders has value other than 0.
Please help me. plz plz

Comment: should write it to a file then each time read from the file

Comment: please include your code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

By different runtimes, I'm assuming you mean running your program at different points in time. The quick answer is no. Here are some options that you may want to consider for sharing the TotalOrders state between different executions of your program.

- Flat File (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)
- Database (MySql)

For instance you could store your TotalOrders variable in a flat file (totals_orders.txt) and read this data in at the beginning of each execution of your program. For a more complicated, but better solution, you could store it in a database (MySQL, Mongo, etc...) - this is extremely helpful if you have other related data you plan on storing (e.g., OrderNumber, SizeOfOrder, etc...).

Comment: First of All Thank You for Providing answer. If I don't have a database and I am working on only Net Beans. Still Is there any chances for storing it and accessing after some time.

Comment: Use a file as in my first suggestion:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html